# mfp cordova run android error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm getting this error when I try to run on android

```
mfp cordova run -d
```

> mobilefirst-cli verb cli
>   process.argv=["/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/IBMnode/bin/node","/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/bin/mobilefirst-cli.js","cordova","run","-d"]
>   mobilefirst-cli verb cli
>   opts={"debug":true,"argv":{"remain":["cordova","run"],"cooked":["cordova","run","--debug"],"original":["cordova","run","-d"]}}
>   mobilefirst-cli verb cli mobilefirst@7.1.0.00.20151130-1653
>   mobilefirst-cli verb cli node@v0.10.36 mobilefirst-cli sill
>   mfp_cordova_cmds running cordova command: "run" with args: ["-d"] ?
>   What platforms do you want to run on? android Searching for list of
>   Devices... ? Which device id do you want to target? 0815f84119921c04 -
>   Samsung RIL v3.0
>
> /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:75
>       throw e;
>             ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at ScreenManager.render (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/mfp_cordova_cmds/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:64:52)
>       at Prompt.render (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/mfp_cordova_cmds/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/list.js:103:15)
>       at Prompt.onSubmit (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/mfp_cordova_cmds/node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/list.js:116:8)
>       at AnonymousObserver.Rx.AnonymousObserver.AnonymousObserver.next (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:1535:12)
>       at AnonymousObserver.Rx.internals.AbstractObserver.AbstractObserver.onNext
>   (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:1469:31)
>       at AnonymousObserver.tryCatcher (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/rx-lite/rx.lite.js:63:31)
>       at AutoDetachObserverPrototype.nextohbocxxg5415yfv:kmf_cordova hannade$

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a newer CLI build? I see the following is available: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_cli_installer_7.1.0.zip

I have a slightly older build installed, 7.1.0.00.20151023-1449, and after creating a MFP Cordova app with the Android environment, I was able to successfully run it in the Android Emulator. I suggest that you will try with the above newer build.

Answer (score 0):

I have the MFP CLI build version 7.1.0.00.20151227-1730 and command

```
    mfp cordova run -d
```

runs alright for an emulator device, however for a physical device, I get the same error

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at ScreenManager.render (/Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/mfp_cordova_cmds/node_modules/inquirer/lib/utils/screen-manager.js:64:52)
```

This appears to be an issue specific to using physical devices to run the cordova application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem in some versions of the CLI and the Foundation team just delivered a fix, which is now available on [Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=7.1.0.0&platform=All&function=all).

Look for interim fix 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201602291240 or later and APAR number
PI56876.  Please give it a look and let me know if it resolves this
problem.